# Display date in WinSCP

Tags: bash, date, winscp

I'm looking for a way to print date of the client or server in WinSCP console.
(`C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com`)

This isn't working.

```
winscp> echo $date
```

Any way we can format the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you get FTP-like commands (what do you get when you type "help" at the console), I'd guess:

```
!date
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [WinSCP `%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp) to print the current *local* date/time:

```
echo %TIMESTAMP#yyyy-dd-mm hh:nn:ss%
```

The above will get you:

```
2017-30-05 11:41:28
```

---

With the SCP (and with the SFTP by callback to the SCP) you can use the [WinSCP `call` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_call) to execute the `date` command on the server to print *remote* time:

```
call date
```

Obviously this assumes the remote system understands the `date` command (most would do).